# Retrieving data with single occurrence of repeated data

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
GROUP BY first_name
HAVING count(first_name) >= 1;
```

How can i retrieve all rows and columns with single occurrence of duplicates? i want to retrieve all the table contents including repeated data that must occur only at once. In a table first_name,last_name are repeated twice but with different in other info. 
Please Help.

Comment: You should add sample data and your expected output both in a tabular format.

Comment: And a sqlfiddle would help people help you, too. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: i'm unable to add picture because of not having Reputation 10. How ccan i over come this? I'm new to stackoverflow. please help.

Comment: I am not even sure your query works.

Comment: Using DISTINCT giving only non repeated data with single occurrence in a single column. How to write for all rows and columns with single occurrence of repeated data.

Comment: What do you mean by *a single occurrence of all duplicates*? It would be really helpful if you added some sample data and expected output...

Comment: You don't need an image. Just create an ascii table like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289068/mysql-unique-email-with-user-that-has-most-currency)

Answer (score 0):

try this Sql Query

```
   SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE FIRST_NAME NOT IN
   (   
       SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM 
       (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FIRST_NAME ORDER BY FIRST_NAME) RNK,FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
       )A WHERE A.RNK=2   
   )
```