# MySQL - Unique email, with user that has most currency

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, duplicates

Say I have a table with data like this:

```
+------------------------------+------------+---------+
| email                        | uname      | credits |
+------------------------------+------------+---------+
| 824@hotmail.com              | barbra     |       6 |
| 123@gmail.com                | smith      |      25 |
| 123@gmail.com                | smithy     |      30 |
| abc@hotmail.com              | another    |      25 |
| def@comcast.net              | rob        |       8 |
| abc@hotmail.com              | ben        |      62 |
| ijk@yahoo.com                | jeb        |       2 |
| ijk@yahoo.com                | joe        |       5 |
+------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

So there is duplicate emails, and you want to send a newsletter out. But you don't want to send multiple of the email to the same email address, and you want to have their username in the email. You probably need to address the user in the email by the username which has more credits, as that account is more likely to be active. So you want a query that'll return data like this:

```
+------------------------------+------------+---------+
| email                        | uname      | credits |
+------------------------------+------------+---------+
| 824@hotmail.com              | barbra     |       6 |
| 123@gmail.com                | smithy     |      30 |
| def@comcast.net              | rob        |       8 |
| abc@hotmail.com              | ben        |      62 |
| ijk@yahii.com                | joe        |       5 |
+------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

So it picks the username that has more credits on their account.

How can I write a query to do this? The only examples I've seen are ones that don't care which username it picks, so you could get the user with less credits.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to determine that smith and smithy are the same user?

Comment: Oops, I meant for them to have the same email. Typo.

Comment: @Bubby4j I think you still have that same typo for the user accounts "jeb" and "joe".

Comment: Fixed that second typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
Select tab.email, tab.uname
From(
    Select email, max(credits) as credits
    From tab
    Group by  email
) x join tab on x.email = tab.email and tab.credits = x.credits
```

Comment: You could probably rename "credit" into "credits" and "name" into "uname" so that the query works with the OP's schema. Here's a working version in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/624d68/3

Comment: +1 I just noticed your answer is identical to the one I posted after you. (Well, almost. It definitely works.)

Answer (score 2):

<s>This should do it:</s>

<s>`SELECT email,uname,MAX(credits) "credits" FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY email;`</s>

**EDIT:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) has some useful information. Try this instead:

```
SELECT `mytab`.`email`, `mytab`.`uname`, `mytab`.`credits`
FROM `my_table` `mytab`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `email`, MAX(`credits`) `max_cred`
  FROM `my_table`
  GROUP BY `email`
) `max` ON `mytab`.`email` = `max`.`email` AND `mytab`.`credits` = `max`.`max_cred`;
```

Comment: That does return the correct credit value, but it'll mix and match the username with the credits. It won't select the user that has the most credits, simply the largest credit amount.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.